# Qpid Benchmark: Have questions related to quid benchmark

Tags: java, performance, benchmarking, amqp, qpid

I am trying to benchmark Qpid with the following use case:

- Default Qpid configs are used(ex: 2GB is the max memory set), broker and 
  client are on the same machine
- I have 1 connection and 256 sessions per connection, each sessions  has a 
  producer and consumer. So, there are 256 producers and 256 consumers
- All the producers/consumers are created before they start 
  producing/consuming messages. Each producer/consumer is a thread and they 
  run parallely
- Consumers start consuming(they wait  with .receive()). All consumer are durableSubscribers
- producers start producing messages, each producer produces only 1 
  message, so there are 256 messages produced in total
- A fanout exchange is used(topic.fanout=fanout://amq.fanout//fanOutTopic), 
  and there are 256 consumers, each consumer receives 256 messages and so 
  there are 256*256 messages received in total

**Following are the response times(RT's) for the messages**:

- Response time is defined as the difference in the time when the 
  message is sent to the broker and the time at which the message is received 
  at the consumer
- min: 144.0 ms
- max: 350454.0 ms
- average: 151933.02 ms
- stddev: 113347.89 ms
- 95th percentile: 330559.0 ms

Is there any thing that I am doing wrong fundamentally?. I am worried about 
the avg response times of "*152 secs*". Is this expected from qpid?. I see 
a pattern here, as the test is running the RT's are increasing linearly 
over time.

Thank you,
Siva.

Comment: "Is there any thing that I am doing wrong fundamentally?". Yes, your question/title is meaningless. Please fix it.

Comment: @Sivananda2510 `Is there any thing that I am doing wrong fundamentally?` Please provide details about your hardware. The total amount of producers and consumers must not be greater than the number of hardware threads. Also check GC logs your - it's very strange when average=stddev. From my point of view this results can not be trusted at all.

Comment: message size has a significant effect on transition time as well.